# Pass generated HTML to a view and replace links with Url.Action

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement to display webpages stored in a database as part of an MVC project. Lets say I have an index page (stored in the db) with a link that points to page1.html (also stored in the db) simply as `<a href="page1.html">`. What I currently have is a controller (call it WebpageGenerator) that takes the page name as an argument, retrieves the html from the database, does some manipulation and passes the resulting string to the view. My view is nothing more than

```
<div class="generatedPage">
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.PageData)
</div>
```

(Yes I've just realised I shouldnt use ViewBag etc etc but I'll deal with that later unless of course this is somehow the cause of my problems...)
Now if I pass along the html for my example index page, the link to page1 will obviously not work. If instead it somehow pointed to `localhost:port/MyProject/WebpageGenerator/page1.html` then it will work.

I've spent the last day struggling with different variations of Url.Action to pass to the View, but nothing is working.

My controller looks something like the following

```
[HttpGet, ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult WebpageGenerator(string id)
{
    StringBuilder pageText = GetHTMLFromDB(id);
    string linkName = GetLink(pageText) //should now contain <a href="page1.html">
    string newLink = "'@Url.Action(\"Index\", \"WebpageGenerator\", new {" + String.Format("id={0}", linkName.OnlyPageName()) + "})'";
    pageText.Replace(linkName, newLink);
    ViewBag.PageData = pageText.ToString();
    return View();
}
```

Unfortunately in the resulting page, the link comes out as `localhost:port/MyProject/@Url.Action(%22Index%22,%20%22WebpageGenerator%22,%20new%20%7Bid=%22page1.html%22%7D)` if I hover over it, and inspecting it shows
`<a href='@Url.Action("Index", "WebpageGenerator", new {id="page1.html"})'>`

Obviously, this link doesnt work. One way I have got this working is to hardcode the url in the controller as such:

```
var addUrl = HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
string newLink = addUrl.Contains("WebpageGenerator") ? linkName.OnlyPageName()) : String.Format("WebpageGenerator/{0}", linkName.OnlyPageName());
```

I'm having to check the referring URL otherwise if I'm viewing page1.html which contains a link to page2.html, the link will point me to localhost:port/MyProject/WebpageGenerator/WebpageGenerator/page2.html

This seems like a dirty fix which I'm not even sure will work when the application is published/deployed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

PS - my first post on SO. Thanks for all the help over the years.

Comment: when you build your `newLink` variable don't put `@Url.Action()` in the string, instead call it. Whatever is returned should be assigned to `newLink`

Comment: Hi @DaveBecker how do I call it in the controller? Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: No probs! Like this: `string newLink = Url.Action("Index", "WebpageGenerator", new { id=linkName.OnlyPageName()});`

Comment: @DaveBecker The sun is shining again! Thank you so much. I can't believe I missed the fact that you can call it in the controller as well.

Comment: Cool I am pleased. I am going to add this as a proper answer so it can help others too.

Comment: I would like to a) thank you for accepting my answer and b) congratulate you on asking your first SO question without it being put on hold or down-voted for no reason. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrapping your call `@Url.Action(...)` into the string. The problem is that the Razor engine won't see this as a directive and will just output it.

Change this to a call to `Url.Action(...)` and it should work fine.

```
string newLink = Url.Action("Index", "WebpageGenerator", new { id=linkName.OnlyPageName()});
```

And the full snippet:

```
    [HttpGet, ActionName("Index")]
    public ActionResult WebpageGenerator(string id)
    {
        StringBuilder pageText = GetHTMLFromDB(id);
        string linkName = GetLink(pageText) //should now contain <a href="page1.html">
        string newLink = Url.Action("Index", "WebpageGenerator", new { id=linkName.OnlyPageName()});
        pageText.Replace(linkName, newLink);
        ViewBag.PageData = pageText.ToString();
        return View();
    }
```

MSDN Url.Action: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx